# Backpropagation Derivative

Tags: derivatives

I am new to AI and currently studying how backpropagation works.

Refer to the diagram below, it seems derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial w}$ can be expressed as $\left ( \sigma(\sigma (wx)) (1-\sigma(\sigma(wx) ) \right )$.

Can anyone please tell me how that expression can be expressed as $f(x)(1-f(x))$?

Thank you for your help.

[Backpropagation Example Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjz51.png)

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = \sigma(\sigma (wx))$. This is a function of $x$, and indeed:
$f(x)(1-f(x)) = (\sigma(\sigma (wx)))(1-\sigma(\sigma (wx)))$.